# Conflict between steinmetz.sty and cancel.sty. Is there a solution?

Tags: packages, incompatibility

The two packages conflict, as can be seen in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{cancel}

\begin{document}

$\cancelto{0}{a+b}$

\end{document}
```

When the `steinmetz` package is loaded, the `cancel` arrow is misplaced:
[image]
How can this conflict be prevented?

Comment: @Gonzalo: Your example works for me. Try to delete all auxiliary files and run your example once more. If it still doesn't work for you, add `\listfiles` at the *very* beginning (even before `\documentclass`) and inspect the logfile for outdated package versions.

Comment: @lockstep: Well, my code doesn't produce compilation errors; but the arrow used to cancel to zero appears in the wrong position after the steinmetz package is loaded.

Comment: @Gonzalo I added an image to show the problem (when you have a bit more reputation you will be able to add images yourself.)

Comment: I get this error with Ubuntu 10.10 texlive. Relevant lines of `\listfiles` are: `  cancel.sty    2000/03/12 v2.1 Cancel math terms
steinmetz.sty    2009/06/14 v1.0 Steinmetz symbol for electrotechnics`

Comment: These seem to be the most up to date versions of these packages (as far as I can tell from CTAN)

Comment: @Gonzalo: You are right but the problem comes from `pict2e` (you can test with `pict2e` instead of `steinmetz`. `steinmetz` loads `pict2e` now I don't know why there is a problem with `pict2e`. I think like me you  have 0 above + and not at the end of the arrow.

Comment: @Altermundus: yes. Loading `pict2e` instead of `steinmetz` produces the same odd result (for both the 0 and the arrow) shown in the image that Alan Munn added to my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage[original]{pict2e}

\usepackage{steinmetz}
\begin{document}

$\cancelto{0}{a+b }$

\end{document}
```

There is a conflict between pict2e and cancel package. By adding `\usepackage[original]{pict2e}` as above, for my case, the problem is solved.

Comment: Without explicitly loading pict2e, adding the `original` option to `\documentclass{article}` solves the conflict as well.

Comment: @Stefan: yes; that also solves the problem.

Comment: or use `\PassOptionsToPackage{original}{pict2e}` before loading `steinmetz`.